# Is the extra damage from an Oathbow doubled on a critical hit?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, damage, attack, critical-hit

Does the extra 3d6 piercing damage of an [Oathbow](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Oathbow#content) get doubled if the attack on the declared enemy is a critical hit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, according to the PHB (p. 196) and basic rules, [critical hits](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#CriticalHits) double the damage of all dice tied to an attack's damage (emphasis mine):

> When you score a critical hit, you get to roll extra dice for the attack's damage against the target. **Roll all of the attack's damage dice twice and add them together.** Then add any relevant modifiers as normal. To speed up play, you can roll all the damage dice at once.
>
> For example, if you score a critical hit with a dagger, roll 2d4 for the damage, rather than 1d4, and then add your relevant ability modifier. **If the attack involves other damage dice, such as from the rogue's Sneak Attack feature, you roll those dice twice as well.**

Comment: Hi Yorrik, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here, and visit the [help] for more info. I hope you don't mind, but I added a D&DBeyond link and quote to support your answer, and removed the part about page numbers. Whilst it's good to reference page numbers if possible, adding a D&DBeyond link is often good enough in it's place, especially if it's part of the SRD (which is free content). If you don't like my edit, you can rollback my edit in the [edit history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/158048/revisions).